# A complicated MySQL JOIN SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok before I begin, let me just state that:

1. I did not create the table.
2. Altering the table is NOT possible.
3. The problem is described "as is". Nothing of significance is left out.

Consider the 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `text` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `rating` (
  `answer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `direction` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY (`answer_id`, `user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now comes the annoying part. The answers table is self explanatory, so I'll just give some examples of rating's rows

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  answer_id  |  direction  |  user_id  |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|      1      |    up       |    23     |
|      1      |    down     |    26     |
|      2      |    up       |    32     |
|      2      |    up       |    42     |
|      2      |    up       |    22     |
|      2      |    down     |    23     |
|      3      |    up       |    45     |
|      3      |    up       |    22     |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Now what I want to do is select all of `answers`, with each answer's corresponding "up" COUNT, "down" COUNT, and the difference between the "up" and "down" COUNT.

Assuming `upcount` is total count of "up"s, `downcount` is total count of "down"s, and `score` is their difference, something like:

```
SELECT [SOMETHING?] AS `upcount`,
[SOMETHING?] AS `downcount`,
(`upcount`-`downcount`) AS `score`,
ans.* FROM answers AS ans LEFT JOIN rating AS r ON ans.id=r.answer_id
[...] ORDER BY `score`, `upcount`
```

Of course, I strongly doubt the solution will look *anything* like the example I gave. I'm just trying to illustrate that each record should have the upcount, downcount, score, and all answers fields.

Any assistance is **greatly** appreciated, thanks!

ps. I **know** that if up and down were 2 separate columns and with numerical values, I can easily use SUM(). But like I said, I did NOT create this table ;)

Comment: So what is the expected output in the above example ?

Comment: Basically a list of records with the upcount, downcount, score, answer's question_id, answer's user_id, and answer's text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a simple join with a GROUP BY clause, but summing up based on an IF statement rather that doing counts:-

```
SELECT a.id, 
        SUM(IF(b.direction='up', 1, 0)) AS upcount, 
        SUM(IF(b.direction='down', 1, 0)) AS downcount,
        SUM(IF(b.direction='up', 1, -1)) AS score
FROM answers a
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating b
ON a.id = b.answer_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY score, upcount
```

EDIT - another possible solution which avoids the IF statements with the SUMs is to join the rating table twice and use a COUNT(DISTINCT ). As user_id is unique for an answer we can count distinct user ids. Down side is it is a bit messier to get the overall score.

```
SELECT a.id, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT b1.user_id) AS upcount, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT b2.user_id) AS downcount, 
        (COUNT(DISTINCT b1.user_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT b2.user_id)) AS score
FROM answers a
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating b1
ON a.id = b1.answer_id
AND b1.direction='up'
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating b2
ON a.id = b2.answer_id
AND b2.direction='down'
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY score, upcount
```

Comment: Wow...worked like a charm! Thank you SO MUCH for resolving this turd situation I have! :D

Comment: No problem. I have added another possible solution which may be better